# How to customize preferences screen title in Lollipop?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I make an Android application trying to support Android Lollipop and previous versions. So, I use `Theme.AppCompat.Light` for my app.

In Android 4.4, Action Bar title is white like I want and preferences screen titles are blacks.

In Android 5.0, Action Bar title is black by default and preferences screen titles are blacks. But, I want my Action Bar title be white on all versions of Android so I used the following customization in my theme for v21 :

```
<item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
```

With this customization, Action Bar title is white like i want but it seems that preferences screen title are also linked to `android:textColorPrimary` in Android 5.0 .

So, my question is the following. Is there a solution to create an Action Bar title with white title and in the same time have preferences screen title with other color like black?

Comment: Use custom style for your toolbar where you set the textcolor to white and then use app:theme=yourtheme inside of the toolbar

Answer (score 1):

Just make two styles.

One with:

```
<item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
```

One with:

```
<item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/black</item>
```

Set your activities with action bars to the white one.
Set you preference activity to the black one.